# Why I'm getting Cannot read property '0' of undefine?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to solve a challenge,but when I access to a two dimensional array, I get an error:

Cannot read property '0' of undefined.

I have tried to solved by add default value of argument, but it did not work.

```js
function minesweeper(matrix= [[]]) {
    
    let res = [];
    
    for(let i=0;i<matrix.length;i++){
        let temp = [];
        for(let j=0;j<matrix.length;j++){
            temp.push( count(i,j,matrix) )   
        }
        res.push(temp);
    }
    
    console.log(res);
}

function count(idx, jdx, matrix = []){
    let count = 0;
    for(let i=-1;i<=1;i++){
        if(i + idx < 0) continue;
        
        for(let j=-1;j<=1;j++){
            if( jdx + j < 0 || (i == 0 && j == 0)) continue;
            
            if(matrix[i+idx][j+jdx] == true) count += 1; // this line
        }
    }
    
    return count;
}

let matrix = [[true, false, false],
[false, true, false],
[false, false, false]];

minesweeper(matrix);
```

Comment: `for(let j=0;j<matrix.length;j++){` <-- um did you mean to loop over it again or the items inside of it?

Comment: `matrix[(i + idx)] is undefined`

Comment: @epascarello yes, i'm trying to check surround  of each element.

Comment: i knew. but how to fix it.

Comment: @vuogvuog well, don't have incorrect logic. I'm not sure what exactly you're trying to do but for `i = -1` and `idx = 0`, you'd try to fetch `matrix[-1]` which doesn't exist.

Comment: @VLAZ no, i checked it before i access to it. ```if( jdx + j < 0 || (i == 0 && j == 0)) continue;```

Comment: Happens at the other end then, when i=1 and idx=(matrix.length - 1)

Comment: @dbramwell thanks, i fixed.

Comment: @vuogvuog in that case you are going out of bounds in the other direction when it's > matrix.length

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When i = 1 and idx = (matrix.length - 1) you end up with matrix[matrix.length] which is undefined. You can fix this by adding a simple check for `matrix[i+idx]`:

```js
function minesweeper(matrix= [[]]) {
    
    let res = [];
    
    for(let i=0;i<matrix.length;i++){
        let temp = [];
        for(let j=0;j<matrix.length;j++){
            temp.push( count(i,j,matrix) )   
        }
        res.push(temp);
    }
    
    console.log(res);
}

function count(idx, jdx, matrix = []){
    let count = 0;
    for(let i=-1;i<=1;i++){
        if(i + idx < 0) continue;
        
        for(let j=-1;j<=1;j++){
            if( jdx + j < 0 || (i == 0 && j == 0)) continue; 
            if(matrix[i+idx] && matrix[i+idx][j+jdx] == true) count += 1; // this line
        }
    }
    
    return count;
}

let matrix = [[true, false, false],
[false, true, false],
[false, false, false]];

minesweeper(matrix);
```